# ¿Cómo comparar cadenas divididas y saber su posición en java?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa el cual compara 2 cadenas divididas por comas
ejemplo:

```
entrada uno=  "anita,lava,la,tina"

entrada dos = "anita,lavo,la,tina"
```

y el programa me tiene que decir que en la posición 2 esta el error, llevo esta parte del programa pero sigue sin compararmelo correctamente

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String predeterminada, entrada;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra predeterminada");
    predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a evaluar");
    entrada = leer.nextLine();
    String[] predeterminada1 = predeterminada.split(",");
    String[] entrada2 = entrada.split(",");
    int j =0;
    for (int x = 0; x < predeterminada1.length; x++) {
        j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < entrada2.length; i++) {
            if(predeterminada1[x]==entrada2[i]){
                j= j+1;
            }
        }
        if(j==0){
            int posicion = x+1;
            System.out.println("No se encontro el caracter en la posición " +posicion+ " - " +entrada2[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí un ejemplo en donde se compara cada una de las textos ingresados:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String predeterminada, entrada;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra predeterminada");
    predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra a evaluar");
    entrada = leer.nextLine();
    String[] predeterminada1 = predeterminada.split(",");
    String[] entrada2 = entrada.split(",");
    //COMPARAR QUE LAS DOS CADENAS TENGAN LA MISMA LONGITUD 
    if (predeterminada1.length == entrada2.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < predeterminada1.length; i++) {
            //COMPARAR CADA CADENA 
            if (!predeterminada1[i].equals(entrada2[i])) {
                System.out.println("Error en Posición " + (i + 1) + ": "
                        + predeterminada1[i] + " no es igual a "
                        + entrada2[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí el resultado:

```
Ingrese la palabra predeterminada
p1,p2,p3
Ingrese la palabra a evaluar
d,p2,fsdfsd
Error en Posición 1: p1 no es igual a d
Error en Posición 3: p3 no es igual a fsdfsd
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, mas completa la explicación no se puede, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar strings usa `.equals()`.

En lugar de:

```
if(predeterminada1[x]==entrada2[i]) {
    j = j+1;
}
```

Sería:

```
if(predeterminada1[x].equals(entrada2[i])) {
    j = j+1;
}
```

`==` compara la referencia (si es el mismo objeto), pero `.equals()` compara los valores.

También puedes usar `Objects.equals()`. El problema de `.equals()` es que si tienes un `null` te va a saltar una excepción. con `Objects.equals()` no.

```
String a = null;
String b = new String("test");

Objects.equals(a, b); // Funciona.
a.equals(b); // Excepcion!
```

Comment: Amigo mil gracias, intente realizarlo con equals pero no ponia [i] , ahora si ya quedo, muchisimas gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Desde Java 8 puedes hacerlo también con [`streams`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/procesamiento-streams-java-se-8-2763402-esa.html).

Aquí compara cada valor de ambas listas y crea una nueva con el índice de la no coincidente.

```
    String sDefault="anita,lava,la,tina";
    String sDynamic="anita,lavo,la,tina";       
    List<String> lstDefault = Arrays.asList(sDefault.split(","));
    List<String> lstDynamic = Arrays.asList(sDynamic.split(","));
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();      

    List<Integer> lstDiff = lstDynamic.stream()
        .peek(e->index.getAndIncrement())
        .filter(e -> !lstDefault.contains(e))
        .map(e->index.get())   
        .collect (Collectors.toList());
    /*Imprimir resultado*/
    lstDiff.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Salida:**

```
2
```

---

Si sólo te interesa guardar el valor, no la posición:

```
    String sDefault="anita,lava,la,tina";
    String sDynamic="anita,lavo,la,tina";       
    List<String> lstDefault = Arrays.asList(sDefault.split(","));
    List<String> lstDynamic = Arrays.asList(sDynamic.split(","));

    List<String> lstDiff = lstDynamic.stream()
        .filter(e -> !lstDefault.contains(e))
        .collect (Collectors.toList());
    /*Imprimir resultado*/
    lstDiff.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Salida:**

```
lavo
```